# store array values in another array using for loop in php

Tags: php, yii

store array values in another array using for loop in php

```
    $sql = "select id,user_email,username,full_name from registration";        
    $connection = Yii::app()->db;
    $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
    $rows = $command->queryAll();
    $email_arr = []; 
       for ($i=0; $i <=count($rows); $i++) { 
          $email_arr[] = $rows[$i]['user_email'];
       }
```

i am getting undefined offset 39 php error anyone can help me please

Comment: your problem is in `$i <=count($rows)`, it should be just `< (less than)` that's because the indexing start from zero, which meanse the 39th element is with index 38.

Comment: yeah it's working now.. thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for ($i=0; $i < count($rows); $i++) {`

Comment: Hi! Code only answers rarely provide much insight, please elaborate what you changed / why your code works and why OP's didn't.

Comment: well technically there is a change in the logic of the for loop @PiyushGupta

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because you are using `$i <= count($rows)` instead of `$i < count($rows)`, since arrays start at 0 and the last index of an array is `count - 1`.

`$rows[count($rows)]` is outside the bounds of the array, which is why you are getting "undefined offset".

You can make what you're writing more maintainable by either using a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) like:

```
$email_arr = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $email_arr[] = $row['user_email'];
}
```

An arguably better way to do this would be to [map the array in a functional way](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) like:

```
$email_arr = array_map(function($row) {
    return $row['user_email'];
}, $rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use condition as follows: use "less than" only if your array has 39 elements then array will start with 0 and end on 38 which will be 38 < 39. Array's subscript start with 0.

```
   for ($i=0; $i < count($rows); $i++) { 
      $email_arr[] = $rows[$i]['user_email'];
   }
```